# QIcon not shown on Ubuntu, works on Windows

Tags: debugging, qt

Hi 
I have a problem in multiple applications which were all developed on a Windows machine. When I build the same apps on Ubuntu and run them, no icons are shown at the File Menu bar alone . 
Works perfectly in windows. Any suggestion

```
 LoadAction = new QAction(tr("&Open file"), this);
 LoadAction->setIcon(QIcon(Dir +"/images/Load.png")); 
 LoadAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Open);
```

I doubled checked the path ,everything is fine ...

Comment: Does Qt give you any kind of warning, can you post the real path too and the output of `ls -la images/Load.png`? Perhaps you have configured the toolbars to display only text?

Comment: Are you sure the visual style you're using supports menu icons at all?

Comment: Which desktop manager are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Set the Qt application object's [AA_DontShowIconsInMenus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) global attribute to be false using

```
application.setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontShowIconsInMenus, false);
```

Another option is to enable menu icons for individual QActions using [QAction::setIconVisibleInMenu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#iconVisibleInMenu-prop).

Answer (score 0):

split that second line , first create the QIcon,then use 
bool QIcon::isNull () const -method to check if the Icon is loadede
and finally set the icon.
If it fails to load from that file, then try creating the path first

```
QString path=Dir+"/images/Load.png";
```

and check if that path is correct

Also remember that for some image formats you need the plugins(but png will work without those,just if you use other formats like jpg,svg)

Answer (score 0):

Paths are case sensative on Linux computers. Are you sure you don't have an upper case file extension?

Windows would be more forgiving.

The step after that would be to output the path to the debug window and do a QFile::exists test on it.